# Javascript - Confirm box to redirect user when they click on exit button

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, confirm

My objective is to when the user clicks on the exit button, it should appear a box with 2 buttons, to confirm or cancel the leave. After the confirm button is clicked, a redirect is needed.

I tried a lot of solutions, but I could only find a solution that I can control what happens after the confirm button.

But I need to do some action after they click on the confirm

My code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return "message"
}
```

That opens a box to confirm the exit, but I can't control the actions after it

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```js
  const result = confirm('Do this?');
    if(result){
      //redirect here
    }
```

Comment: The confirm box dont appear